# Finding adjacent difference in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a js array with the following elements

```
var xy = [
  [11,21],
  [20,10],
  [36,70],
  [42,70],
]
```

I want to find the difference between every adjacent elements and store in another array

```
xdiff = [9,16,6]
ydiff = [11,60,0]
```

I have tried with

```
for(i=0; i<xy.length; i++)
{
  xdiff.push(Math.abs(xy[i][0]-xy[i+1][0]))
  ydiff.push(Math.abs(xy[i][1]-xy[i+1][1]))
}
```

But it’s giving wrong output.

Comment: "*But it’s giving wrong output.*" - while your question appears to have been correctly answered, please consider making an [edit] to your question in order that we know in what way the output is wrong, that way future visitors are able to establish whether they're suffering the same problem as you and whether or not the answers to your question are worth reading to solve their own problem.

Answer (score 1):

The attempt runs in to an error when it arrives at the last `xy` coordinate. It attempts to look ahead using `xy[i + 1]`, but returns `undefined`.

Hence the error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

To fix the issue, only loop up to the element *before* the last element:

```js
var xy = [
  [11, 21],
  [20, 10],
  [36, 70],
  [42, 70],
],
  xdiff = [],
  ydiff = [];
    
for (i = 0; i < xy.length - 1; i++) {
  //                     ^^^^ stop before the last element

  xdiff.push(Math.abs(xy[i][0] - xy[i + 1][0]))
  ydiff.push(Math.abs(xy[i][1] - xy[i + 1][1]))
}

console.log(xdiff, ydiff);
```